# bootstrap collapse without buttons (and use text link instead)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know if it is possible to NOT have to use buttons but rather have user click on text link to activate Bootstrap Collapse?  Below is the code currently used. This action is currently being used in WordPress.  Thanks!

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">CLICKABLE TEXT WOULD GO HERE INSTEAD OF BUTTON</button>

<div class="collapse out" id="demo">&nbsp;
<p>Hidden Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a "a" tag, with the same elements of button.

```
<a data-target="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">
    CLICKABLE TEXT WOULD GO HERE INSTEAD OF BUTTON
</a>

<div class="collapse out" id="demo">
    <p>
        Hidden Content goes here.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "a" tag and just put href="#" while using the same events. Or you could just wire up the event handler yourself. 
Getbootstrap.com has all the examples laid out very well. I have used images , icons and other items to simulate the button.

Comment: Dear Jason - 

To clarify: So swap out <button class="btn btn-primary data-target="......> and use <a href="#demo"....> instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that or you can actually just re-class the button to use btn btn-link per http://get bootstrap.com/CSS/#button-tags